# What answer is expected by "May I have your name ?"

Tags: idioms

I'm quite fuzzy about the information asked on the phone by people asking "May I have your name ?"

Do they want the first/given name or the last/family name ?

Please answer for both UK and US culture.

Comment: If you answer with either they will ask you for the other one. Nobody can write down spoken names in English cold without asking for spelling clarification, so whichever name you start with there will be a pause while writing, and maybe a spelling enquiry, and repeat for the other part(s) of your name.

Comment: Usually it's asked before being connected to someone else.

Comment: Do you know if I can do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In business conversation in the US, the response to *May I have your name* is your full name, usually in the form *given* then *family (surname)*.

Occasionally a respondent may offer just a title and a surname, as in *Dr. Jekyll*, *Reverend Jones*, or *Professor Moriarty*.

Also occasionally, a close friend or family may say *It's her brother, Bob*.

In all other cases, a full name is usually needed to help the call recipient know whether is it John Smith or Jane Smith and to brace themselves accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In America, if you call someone, and they ask for your name, you answer the question completely enough so that the person who picks up the phone knows who you are.

If you are the call-ee's spouse intimate, "It's me," is usually enough.

This answer will also suffice if you are a close relative and have an instantly recognizable voice.

If you are a friend of someone that the call-ee knows well, your full name will suffice.   "It's Bill Swenson."   THEN you answer any questions about you that the call-ee puts to you.

But if you are not known to the call-ee or anyone that the call-ee knows, and the call-ee asks for your name, volunteer not only your full name, but any and all information with which the call-ee can identify you, ESPECIALLY whatever organization on whose behalf you are making the call.

There is NOTHING more infuriating than a telemarketer who says "Hi, Greg," or asks "Is Jill there?" by way of feigning an imaginary acquaintance with the call-ee or someone the call-ee knows.

By the way, this is more a fact about ettiquette than it is about English grammar.